# Does using a WPF control inside MFC oblige to use -NET virtual machine?

Tags: c++, wpf, mfc

I want to embed a Bing Maps layer with WPF inside an MFC control. Does this mean that my MFC app will no longer be native, but managed code (and therefore running on the .NET virtual machine?)

Comment: there is a way to test this =) publish your app, put it in a machine without .net

Comment: @Robson: Nonsense. The Bing Maps WPF Control has a dependency on the .NET framework. That doesn't imply, that the hosting application will all of a sudden turn into managed code. The MFC application continues to be compiled to native code, and merely hosts the CLR used for the WPF Control. manatttta: There is no virtual machine in the .NET framework. All IL code is compiled into native code before being executed. IL code (in contrast to Java Byte Code) is not interpreted.

Comment: @IInspectable thank you. however, I figure that the .NET Framework and using managed code has some performance drawbacks, and my app requires high performance.

Comment: Don't make assumptions about performance, until you have a working implementation, and a profiler that indicates an issue. Managed code usually exhibits performance that is within 10% of unmanaged code. Occasionally, managed code runs even faster. In particular, memory allocations from the managed heap are blazingly fast, several orders of magnitude faster than memory allocations on the unmanaged heap.

Comment: @IInspectable surely the application would not magically turn to managed code, I was just suggesting a way to test, to help the OP get the answer in an experimental way.

Comment: @Robson: How does your proposed procedure to *"put it in a machine without .net"* answer the question *"Does this mean that my MFC app will no longer be native?"* The WPF Control has a dependency on the .NET Framework, and the application will not run on a platform that cannot resolve the dependencies. So now you know, that the application doesn't run without the .NET Framework installed. What does that tell you about the MFC host application? I cannot believe I had to write this...

Comment: publishing the app to a machine without .net would have made the app open, but the puglin would obviously not work, so the op could sort out that his app wouldn't turn into managed code.

Comment: @Robson: Dependencies of an embedded control are resolved at load-time. On a machine without the .NET Framework installed, the application will fail to run. You are describing a system that does not coincide with reality. I have no idea, what a puglin is, so I don't know if it will work or not (for an arbitrary definition of "work").